# How would I subtract N specific rows from a PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, sample

I have a dataframe, `nsdf`, which I would like to sample 5% of. `nsdf` looks something like this:

```
col1
8
7
7
8
7
8
8
7
(... and so on)
```

I sample `nsdf` like so:

```
sdf = nsdf.sample(0.05)
```

I would then like to remove the rows in `sdf` from `nsdf`. Now, here I would think I could use `nsdf.subtract(sdf)`, but that would remove *all* rows in `nsdf` that match any row from `sdf`. For example, if `sdf` contained

```
col1
7
8
```

Then *every* row in `nsdf` would be removed, as they are all either a 7 or an 8. Is there a way to remove *only* the number of 7's/8's (or whatever else) that appears in `sdf`? More specifically, in this example I would like to end up with an `nsdf` that contains the same data but one 7 fewer and one 8 fewer.

Comment: Can't you just do a `nsdf.sample(0.95)` to obtain the desired result or am I missing something?

Comment: @RicS I'm unsure if that would be an option, although I appreciate the insight. I think I would still have to end up using `exceptAll()` instead of `subtract()` to remove sampled rows in the case that there were duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of [`subtract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract) is to remove all instances of a row in the left dataframe if present in the right dataframe. What you are looking for is [`exceptAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll).

## Example:

**Data Setup**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(7,), (8,), (7,), (8,)], ("col1", ))
```

### Scenario 1:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(7,), (8,)], ("col1", ))

df.exceptAll(df1).show()
```

#### Output

```
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|   7|
|   8|
+----+
```

### Scenario 2:

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(7,), (7,), (8,)], ("col1", ))

df.exceptAll(df2).show()
```

#### Output

```
+----+
|col1|
+----+
|   8|
+----+
```